# How do I dock html input element?

Tags: html

There are some inputs with labels like:

```js
function hide(target) {
  document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label id="label_lname" for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>
<!-- other inputs here... -->

<a href="#" onclick="hide('lname');hide('label_lname');">Hide Last Name</a>
```

If I hide `fname` (with JavaScript), phone should move to the position where `fname` was.
If phone is hidden, the next element should be moved to its position and so forth.
Is there some kind of `dock top` property?

Playground: When clicking on `Hide Last Name`, the `Last Name` element should be hidden and phone should be moved to its position.
https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/ukh8x5p7/

The behaviour should be like with C# DockStyle.Top:
If buttons are arranged one below the other and one is made invisible, all buttons below are moved up.

Comment: It does not do that automatically? Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant JS and CSS

Comment: Why would phone move into fname's spot? What are the rules here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `<br>` tag. If you set `display:none` for root element that contains `input, label and br` tag it works correctly.

```js
function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>

<div id="lname">
<label id="label_lname" for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text"  name="lname">
<br><br>
</div>

<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br> 


<a href="#" onclick="hide('lname');hide('label_lname');">Hide Last Name</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not move is you need to not have the `<br><br>`

I would delegate and use CSS to space the fields

Also wrapping the label around the field saves effort when you do not need the label somewhere other than next to the field

```js
const toggle = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("toggleField")) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.id).classList.toggle("hide")
  }
};
document.getElementById("toggleDiv").addEventListener("click", toggle)
```

```css
label {
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
  display: block
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label id="fnameLabel">First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></label>
<label id="lnameLabel">Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"></label>
<label id="phoneLabel">Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"></label>

<div id="toggleDiv">
  <a href="#" class="toggleField" data-id="fnameLabel">Toggle First Name</a>
  <a href="#" class="toggleField" data-id="lnameLabel">Toggle Last Name</a>
</div>
```